Razor Pay not calling callback_url
So basically, razorpay popup is opening, payment being success but the callback url isn't getting called:
               var options = {
                    "key": data.razorpay_key,
                    "amount": data.amount,
                    "currency": data.currency,
                    "name": "BusinessCard4U",
                    "image": "{{websitelogo.image.url}}",
                    "description": "Payment for digital card subscription",
                    "order_id": data.razorpay_order_id,
                    "callback_url": "{% url 'PaymentSuccess' %}",
                    "handler": function (response){
                        // Handle Razorpay success callback
                    },
                    "theme": {
                        "color": "#5EB9F0"
                    },
                };

This is data i am passing... it has callback url as you can see... but neither anything is getting printed, nor it's being called.
I tried using redirect: true variable to see if that works but that made the payment failed.
Thank You!

As per my knowledge {% url 'PaymentSuccess' %} template tag in Django generates a relative URL, and in callback_url of Razor Pay you need an Absolute URL, URL something like this(change as per your configuration) "http://127.0.0.1:8000/razorpay/success/".
So, First, try it by providing a static Absolute URL("callback_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/razorpay/success/") and test the payment process whether it works as you expected If it works you can create the dynamic callback_url.
your views must be look something like below:
Also, make sure that you have handled the POST request method. as Razor Pay call back URL has it's method and parameters as shown in documentation(https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-gateway/callback-url/)
try like below:
var options = {
  ... // existing options
  callback_url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment-success/' // adjust URL as per your configuration,
  redirect: true
}

Cross-verify that your view looks like something.
@csrf_exempt
def callback(request):
    if "razorpay_signature" in request.POST:
        # If payment is successful
        payment_id = request.POST.get("razorpay_payment_id", "")
        provider_order_id = request.POST.get("razorpay_order_id", "")
        signature_id = request.POST.get("razorpay_signature", "")
        
        # your further code
        return render("#your page redirect") 
    else:
        payment_id = json.loads(request.POST.get("error[metadata]")).get("payment_id")
        
        # your further code
        return render("#your page redirect")


Nothing changed... it's still the same bro.

Could you please share your urls.py code for PaymentSuccess URL?

path('payment-success/',views.CallBackUrl, name='PaymentSuccess')

Have you added redirect option as shown in the documentation and also passed the absolute URL?

I've wrote in question, i tried adding but it showed payment failed after selecting any type

yeah, but you haven't passed the absolute URL at that time, right? I'm saying it that try it with both(redirect and absolute URL) options also I've updated the answer just cross verify that your options and view looks like that.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Leaving Everything... IT WORKS! Thanks!

Most likely your callback_url was wrong.
http://localhost:8000 is not the same as http://127.0.0.1:8000.
In production try using https://yoursite.com instead of https://www.yoursite.com
FYI redirect: true is not necessary to send a POST request to callback_url.
According to the docs:

redirect (optional) (boolean)
Determines whether to post a response to the event handler post payment completion or redirect to Callback URL. callback_url must be passed while using this parameter.
Possible values:
true: Customer is redirected to the specified callback URL in case of payment failure.
false (default): Customer is shown the Checkout popup to retry the payment with the suggested next best option.

Bit confusing, here's how it works:
redirect: false in practice:

OTP page opens in a new tab
Payment success closes the OTP new-tab, then shows a "Success" page in the Razorpay modal with a Redirecting... timer
Payment failure takes you back to original page with Razorpay modal

redirect: true in practice:

OTP page opens in same tab
Payment success POSTs to callback_url "instantly" without showing the "Success" screen on payment modal and no Redirecting... timer
Payment failure is handled by error handler in your server's POST route

